# Setting Custom Validation Rules with Jquery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I'm trying to set some custom rules for a form and am using the aforementioned [Jquery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), but I don't really know to revise the examples given to accomplish what I want to do.

What I want to do is set up a condition where the option selected in a "country" input changes the required number of digits needed to validate a phone number text input. For my example, I tried setting something up where if the selected country is Canada, the amount of digits required in the telephone input is 10, otherwise the required amount is 12.

Before I took notice of the documentation for addMethod, I attempted inserting a custom conditional statement in a small sample form like so...

```
<form id='myform'>
        <select name="country" placeholder="country" id="country">
                <option value="">Select a country</option>
                <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="Elsewhere">Elsewhere</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
<script>
$phoneDigits = 10;      

$('#country').change(function(){
    if($('#country').val() == 'Elsewhere'){
        $phoneDigits = 12;
    }else{
        $phoneDigits = 10;
    }
});

    $("#myform").validate(
  {
    rules: 
    {
      fullname: 
      {
        required: true
      },
      email: 
      {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
        country: 
      {
        required: true,
      },
        phonenumber: 
      {
        required: true,
        minlength: $phoneDigits
      }
    },
    messages: 
    {
      fullname: 
      {
        required: "Please enter your name"
      },
      email: 
      {
        required: "Please enter your email address."
      },
     country: 
      {
        required: "Please select a country."
      },
    phonenumber: 
      {
        required: "Please enter your phone number."
      }
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

This almost worked but the $phoneDigits variable wouldn't change within the validate function. I am receptive to any ideas that could improve this logic so that it works, but otherwise, can anyone help me find out how I can [revise one of these examples into doing what I want instead?](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('$input').rules('add', options)` as the plugin [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules)

Here's your code..

```
<form id='myform'>
    <select name="country" placeholder="country" id="country">
            <option value="">Select a country</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="Elsewhere">Elsewhere</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

 $("#myform").validate(
 {
    rules: 
    {
      fullname: 
      {
        required: true
      },
      email: 
      {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      country: 
      {
        required: true,
      },
      phonenumber: 
      {
        required: true
      }
 },
 messages: 
 {
    fullname: 
    {
        required: "Please enter your name"
    },
    email: 
    {
        required: "Please enter your email address."
    },
    country: 
    {
        required: "Please select a country."
    },
    phonenumber: 
    {
        required: "Please enter your phone number."
    }
 }
   }); 
   var obj = {minlength: 0,
    messages: {
      minlength: '')
    }
  };
  $('#country').change(function(){
    if($('#country').val() == 'Elsewhere'){
        obj.minlength = 12;
        obj.messages.minlength = 'Required at least 12 digit';
    }else{
        obj.minlength = 10;
        obj.messages.minlength = 'Required at least 10 digit';
    }
  // And lastly...
  $( "#phonenumber" ).rules( "add", obj);
  });
```

Comment: Welp, I must have missed that page. Thank you very much for your answer Prs, it's all working now.